# I want to use Entity Framework + ASP Identity but I don't want EF to generate tables for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have created new ASP MVC 5 app (with asp identity).
I use `IdentityDbContext` class to put all my domain objects inside.

```
public class SecurityContext : IdentityDbContext{
...
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

When I first time created user all database tables were created (identity tables) including my `Country` table.
But now I added new table in database (**created from Management Studio**) and added in `IdentityDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

But when I run the app now I get error:

> The model backing the 'SecurityContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

If I delete all tables and run app again `City` will be created but I wan't to be more flexible.
So what I want to do is that I can create all database tables and to create my POCO classes in project later so I can use EF for data access.
I don't want EF to create classes for me (*I feel more secure when connect those things alone*).
Also (*I know that it is possible but just don't know how*) can I **prevent asp Identity to create tables alone**?
To sum whole question. I want to use EF but I want to create my database myself including `Identity` tables. How can I do this?

Comment: Use EF Database First http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off the EF initializer and manage the tables and mappings yourself.

Disable the database initializer in the constructor like this...

```
public SecurityContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<SecurityContext>(null);
}
```

Then you can just take the schema that EF has created thus far and manage it yourself (you can remove the migrations history table). I recommend using a SQL Server Database project so that you can source control your schema. It's now up to you to update the DbContext when the schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable it through configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>    
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType YourNameSpace.SecurityContext, YourLibraryName" value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```